# Looking For A Soy Flour Substitution

Tags: bread

I have found what looks like a wonderful recipe for a low carb yeast bread that I really want to make. It only has 3.4g of net carbs/slice, which is gonna be pretty hard to beat! Especially if this is as good as it looks! [Gabi's Low-carb Yeast Bread](http://lowcarbyum.com/gabis-low-carb-yeast-bread/#comment-39175) I only have one problem. One of the ingredients is soy flour. I'm simply completely uncomfortable knowingly eating any soy product that is not fermented.

So my question is, is it possible to substitute another product in its place, and if so what? Could I possibly increase one or more of the other dry ingredients already used in the recipe? (ie: vital wheat gluten flour, cup oat flour, flax seed meal,coarse unprocessed wheat bran) I am also curious what soy flour "brings to the table", so to speak. What it does for a recipe that makes it such a "go to" ingredient in low-carb recipes.

I would greatly appreciate anyone's knowledgeable assistance!

[image: Gabi's Low-carb Bread]

Answer (score 6):

It's a bean flour, so substitute another bean flour - chickpea/garbanzo is perhaps the most commonly available one, IME.

Beans bring protein, fiber and fat to the recipe. Soy has considerably more fat (oil) than chickpeas, so you might need to add some oil (or higher-oil things like nut or sunflower seed butters.)

"Fermented soybean powder" is available, and would presumably be more or less equivalent to soy flour.

Comment: Ecnerwal - Thank you for your very helpful and useful reply!

Comment: @user45244 if you are satisfied with the answer, please *[accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)* it, in addition to [upvoting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow).